# How does matplotlib.pyplot determine x and y axis labels and scale plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am having trouble understanding how matplotlib.pyplot determines x and y labels (default) placed on the x and y axis and, relatedly, how to change the intervals of these labels *and scale the plot accordingly*. This last bit is important, because I'm getting some very strange behavior. In particular, the default graph comes out as follows:

[image]

To be sure, this graph plots the data correctly. However, I don't want the y-axis to neither have so many labels, nor have them so precise. So I added the following bit of code to my program:

```
ax.set_ylim(bottom=y_min, top=y_max)
y_tick_marks = list(np.arange(y_min, y_max, (y_max - y_min)/10))
y_labels = [round(elem, 4) for elem in y_tick_marks]
plt.yticks(y_tick_marks, y_labels)
```

And I get the following graph:
[image]

Which seems ridiculous, because I should be able to see some of both graphs (I realize the greatest y value is not the same as the previous graph). So I then erased the previous block of code and included the following (note that they are the same except one line is omitted):

```
y_tick_marks = list(np.arange(y_min, y_max, (y_max - y_min)/10))
y_labels = [round(elem, 4) for elem in y_tick_marks]
plt.yticks(y_tick_marks, y_labels)
```

I did this because I suspected something was going on with the scaling of the graph given the difference between graph 1 and 2 above. I think I am correct, because I received the following graph:

[image]

This is very strange because the first graph insinuated the y values of the second graph would fit, but in this third graph we see that the second graph is just a very small portion. So I ran a print statement:

```
print(ax.get_ylim())
```

Which gave the following output:

```
(-1.1500000000000001, 24.15)
```

What in the world is going on? It seems that matplotlib is admitting to scaling the y values in some way, but making sure to relate these scaled y values to their original values through the y-axis labels.

I realize that I have not included much code, but I did not want to force anyone to read a bunch of code if it was unnecessary to answering the question--to be sure, I have printed all y-values and triple-checked my input into the graphing methods. I can add more code if requested but the graphs speak for themselves.

A general solution would be nice, but I would also really appreciate a lower-level explanation of this behavior if it can be provided. Thanks to anyone who tries to answer this.

Comment: Restart from scratch, but make sure to use **numbers**, not strings as input data.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had type converted the values of the y axis when creating the ticks and labels, but had overlooked doing so when plotting. You are awesome. What's the protocol here btw? Should I just take this question down or leave it up?